How do I merge scattered and intertwined projects from SSIS, stored procedures, and Access databases into one SSIS project with the help of a ChatGPT?
I want to merge some projects into one. The projects have grown over a long time, some have grown a lively life of their own so that there seem to be intertwined or repeating workflows among the projects. On the whole, it is a vast load of steps with many code snippets that you do not understand even at a second and third glimpse.
Some projects are small like a list of stored procedures or some Access databases, some are SSIS projects of many SSIS files. My aim is to find out the core of the workflows and the nested layers around it in both code and workflow. I want to ask the bot and take the answer as the benchmark for my further work to build one SSIS core project out of the many scattered project. The aim is to build tables in a relational database that feed all of the now seven projects. There are already tables, views and other data flows. I want to build as few as there can be.
How should I work with a GPT chat (no matter which version) to build one main SSIS project from many projects of many kinds?
(It goes without saying that any input in ChatGPT needs to be anonymized)


You need to enter all of the projects in one chat, only then, the bot can know what sticks them altogether. Therefore, you need to mind the size of the input, and the bot must understand it:


I can paste stored procedures as they are, they have the smallest size you can get.
For MS Access databases, I have some VBA code to wrap up their tables and queries, see How do I get the full sql code for all queries in all MS Access databases of a folder?, export that to xml and feed it to the chat.
For SSIS projects, I need to slim down the files, see How do I shrink down an SSIS project of two million characters to a core size that chatgpt 4 omni can eat and digest to wrap it up in C# and UML?.


Any input must be anonymized. For the SSIS projects, this is inside the code.
Output email_map file for a full SSIS project:

For any file at all, you can follow How do I anonymize the e-mails inside of code or text so that I do not need to share them with ChatGPT? to replace any e-mail with a dummy e-mail.



Getting a merger of the projects works:

Ask the bot to answer in such a way that a copy of the answer would give enough insights to the bot to work further on the fully merged project without knowing the project inputs anymore.
Ask for C# code for an SSIS-Script component that merges all of the steps.
Ask for the same C# code for each project on its own, with the aim of merging them afterwards so that the bot cares for the same structure and same control and data flows.
Ask another time for C# code, but now for one big C# code that splits the code into the old projects. This will help you finding out which of the merged code comes from which project, and also, you can check all of those projects against the input files and harmonize names where the bot did not find a link that you might know about. For example, you should migrate old code from a legacy server to the new server if you want to get good matches among the new server. If column names and tables do not match, and if you do not show a mapping table, the bot might not be able to guess a good merge.
You can and should also ask for a merger of all projects in UML together with SQL code.
You should ask a second time for further UML to dig deeper into UML since the bot will often begin with an quick answer while it may know more. To get the best outcome, put it to the the free choice of the bot whether it wants to dig deeper and whether it wants to take other UML tools as well since the bot knows best what is missing or helpful.
Ask for any further workflow overview that the bot likes for its own understanding which does not need to be a UML tool anymore. Follow the answer, and often, it helps to ask the bot a second time to get deeper answers.

Ask for the SSIS workflow that the bot would build from all of this, with all SQL code and any splits, joins, lookups and other tools that it may need.
In my company frontend of GPT 4 omni, I cannot go over the border of roughly 500,000 characters, see How do I count the true number of characters (with any whitespaces) or words in a GPT Chat to find out the border of the chat size?. If you reach that border, you should ask the last SSIS workflow question right away after entering all of the projects since that will help you the most to build up the workflow.
But the smartest merger of all is a thorough C# code that you then try to debug. Understand it with the set of UML, split it up into new C# scripts until you can fall back to the good old SSIS tools that do not need any C# anymore.
Mind that I did not set up "the big SSIS project" in the end, I did not build an SSIS project from all of the projects. I stopped since it became clear during further work and talk that some projects needed to be migrated and therefore could not match the other projects by any means, and it was clear that the migration to another server, on top of another project's data, would already be the most needed merger.
The output of the chat was still helpful:

as an overview during the migration,
for process talk,
as a benchmark.

It is quickly done and worth the tokens and time.
